# Using Ajax Request with PHPUnit and Laravel testing

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, phpunit

I am doing tests in Laravel with phpunit. I run a test that inserts that into a textbox and press a button. Then, theres an Ajax Post that sends the info to the server and returns the response. If I return a string has the following code, in the test I should get that string correct?

I have the following controller:

```
class MyController extends Controller{
    public static function createNewComplaintStep_2(){
          return "error";
    }
}
```

The route:

```
Route::post('/createNewComplaint_Step2', 'MyController@createNewComplaintStep_2');
```

The view with form and ajax method:

```
<form id="formToSubmit" data-value="createNewComplaint_Step2" class="form-horizontal">
                {!! csrf_field() !!}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Customer:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <input class="form-control" name="customer_name" required>                            
                    </div>
                 </div>
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="subBTN"\>
         </form>
(...)
<script>
$( '#formToSubmit' ).on( 'submit', function(e) {
    var href = $(this).data('value');   
    e.preventDefault();     
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: href,
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function( msg ) {
            $("#container-fluid").html(msg);
            $('.se-pre-con').hide();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

The phpunit test:

```
$this->visit('/createNew')
            ->type('NAME', 'customer_name')
            ->press('subBTN')
            ->see('error');
```

Is there something wrong? Because if I run the code, I get error

> Failed asserting that the page contains the HTML [error]. Please check the content above

**The content above is the view that is above**. It seems that the ajax request is not working with phpunit.
Any suggestions??

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You are working with jquery Ajax, which is a **client side** **scripting** **language**, basically executed in the browser at **runtime** it cannot be used by Laravel in tests.

Here your Ajax is not even execute so how can you get the string that's why this error is coming.

But you can try some **extensions/drivers** for laravel that can enable this feature.
Just check out Selenium:-
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/testing/has-anyone-tried-laravel-integrated-package-in-laravel-52